# How to get the Percentage using MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I want to find the percentage of claims in run time.
I learn that it can be achieved using calculated measure, but I do not know how to do that. Please guide me how to find the percentage of claims((line count/grandtotoal) *100).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
WITH 
   MEMBER [Measures].[PercentageOfAll] AS
       [Tmp Claim Dim].[Claimno].CURRENTMEMBER
       /
      ([Tmp Claim Dim].[Claimno].[All])
   ,FORMAT_STRING = 'Percent';
SELECT 
    {[Measures].[Tmp Claim Dim Count],
     [Measures].[PercentageOfAll]} ON 0,
     [Tmp Claim Dim].[Claimno].MEMBERS ON 1 
FROM [ACOE PI];
```

If you want the above to just apply to the measure `[Tmp Claim Dim Count]` then you could use tuples with this measure in your new measure:

```
WITH 
   MEMBER [Measures].[PercentageOfAll_ClaimCnt] AS
      ([Tmp Claim Dim].[Claimno].CURRENTMEMBER, [Measures].[Tmp Claim Dim Count])
       /
      ([Tmp Claim Dim].[Claimno].[All], [Measures].[Tmp Claim Dim Count]) 
   ,FORMAT_STRING = 'Percent';
SELECT 
    {[Measures].[Tmp Claim Dim Count]} ON 0,
     [Tmp Claim Dim].[Claimno].MEMBERS ON 1 
FROM [ACOE PI];
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. I was looking for the second query. it is working fine .Now i understood how to add these queries in calculated measure and browse it in my report. Getting the result what i expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt and try this :

```
WITH 
   MEMBER [Measures].[Percentage] AS
   [Measures].[line count]/
   ([Measures].[grandtotoal]), 
   FORMAT_STRING = 'Percent';
SELECT 
{[Measures].[Percentage]} ON COLUMNS, 
FROM [yourcube]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question i s how would i derive the grantotal. in the above screenshot shared (claim1 count is 4 and grandtotal is 7).so i need to derive (4/7).

Comment: Where do you get the measures `[Measures].[line count]` and `[Measures].[grandtotoal]`? - I see no reference to them in the question.